# How to parse string with long milliseconds (nanoseconds) part to DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to figure-out the right string format of the following given date-time literal:

```
18-JUN-13 12.17.36.000000000
```

Using [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), I managed to composed the following format:

`"d'-'MMM'-'y'T'h'.'m'.'s'.'fff"`

But when using the `DateTime.ParseExact`, the parsing fails with a `FormatException`: *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*.

My code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("18-JUN-13 12.17.36.000000000", "d'-'MMM'-'y'T'h'.'m'.'s'.'fff", null);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff
```

with *english based* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) for example. I'm on mobile right now, so I can't try it :(

*AFAIK*, milliseconds part parsing limit is `7`, that's why you can't parse your string *without* manipulate it. You can use it like;

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("18-JUN-13 12.17.36.0000000",
                             "dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.fffffff",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Looks like that's why probably we have [The `"fffffff"` custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#fffffffSpecifier) as top character of milliseconds. From docs;

> Although it is possible to display the ten millionths of a second
>   component of a time value, **that value *may* not be meaningful**. The
>   precision of date and time values depends on the resolution of the
>   system clock. On the Windows NT 3.5 (and later) and Windows Vista
>   operating systems, the clock's resolution is approximately 10-15
>   milliseconds.

You asked;

> How would you have manipulate the string?

*Well*, one way to get last index of comma and substring it to 8 index after that like;

```
string s = "18-JUN-13 12.17.36.000000000";
var dateString = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(".") + 8);
```

Comment: The important thing with the 'f' formatter is that it represents one digit of sub-second precision.  It has to match the number of input decimal places for it to match ParseExact.

Comment: Have you tried it? It seems that you cannot use 9`f`. The input string's length must also match.

Comment: Actually the limit is 7.  After 7 f's it will give you an exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right. I'm on mobile now, so I can't try it correctly. Looks like the limit of milliseconds parsing is `7`. I think my second example will work.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Yes, you are right. Since I'm on mobile, I couldn't write it on first time. Thank you.

Comment: @YairNevet Edited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: The quoted text is saying that when formatting with `ffff`/`FFFF` and beyond you might end up with more digits than the system clock can represent; if you're parsing or the value to be formatted didn't originate from the Windows clock (e.g. `DateTime.Now`) then I don't think it applies. Instead, the reason you can't go beyond `fffffff` is because `0.0000001` seconds is 100 nanoseconds, which happens to be one tick, the smallest interval a `DateTime` can represent. It's unfortunate that neither the exception message nor the documentation calls out this limitation, which seems easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly parse (i.e. `ParseExact()`) a time string with more than seven digits after the decimal point *unless*, as suggested by [juharr's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209021/datetime-format-throws-exception#comment100924976_57209021) on [DateTime format throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57209021/150605), you parse the excess digits as [literal characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals):

```csharp
string before = "18-JUN-13 12.17.36.000000000";
string format = "d'-'MMM'-'y' 'h'.'m'.'s'.'fffffff'00'";
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(before, format, null);
string after = value.ToString(format);

Console.WriteLine(before);// 18-JUN-13 12.17.36.000000000
Console.WriteLine(after); // 18-Jun-13 12.17.36.000000000
```

Otherwise, you'll need to truncate the excess digits, as in [Soner Gönül's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28409644/150605).

It's unfortunate that neither the exception message nor the documentation calls out why `fffffff`/`FFFFFFF` is the limit, because the reason is simple but easy to overlook.

`0.0000001` seconds is:

- One ten-millionth of a second, or...
- 100 nanoseconds, or...
- One [tick](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime#datetime-resolution)

A tick is the smallest interval a `DateTime` can represent.  Format strings such as `ffffffff` (eight significant digits) and beyond can't be valid because that would require a `DateTime` to be able to store fractions of a tick.  While "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" *does* describe the problem, in this case it's not just that the input doesn't match the specified format, it's also that the input can't be precisely represented by a `DateTime`, anyways.

Answer (score -1):

You have a bunch of single quotes in there which isn't a correct format. Try this

```
DateTime.ParseExact("18-JUN-13 12.17.36.000000000", "d-MMM-yTh.m.s.fff", null);
```

Comment: NOTE: unless you use the single quotes, the date-time formatter may change the dash to a different locale specific separator like a slash.  I've been bitten by this one when parsers started to fail after someone changed their default locale.

Comment: Single quotes [are valid](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals) and an alternative to escaping characters individually with ```\```; see [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) where several of the patterns are expressed using quotes.